# Need current version of Audacious on Raspberry Pi

Tags: audacious

I ran these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade 
apt show audacious
```

...and got:

```
Package: audacious  
Version: 3.6.2-2
```

though the current version is 3.9 and on an Intel-PC I got:

```
Package: audacious  
Version: 3.9-3~webupd8~xenial0
```

So, where can I find a current audacious for Raspberry?

I tried to compile from source, but got:

```
/usr/local/src/audacious-3.9/src/libaudcore/plugin-load.cc:68:undefined reference to `g_module_open
```